# Mongoose validation error while sending data using ExpressJS post route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a Mean stack application, I have defined an expressjs backend post route to store some data on server, but its not working and giving mongoose validation error on fields, although I have provided all the fields.

```
message:"Path `controlType` is required."
name:"ValidatorError"
path:"controlType"
properties:{type: "required", message: "Path `{PATH}` is required.", path: "controlType"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

If I print **req.body** it prints all the fields with their correct values, see the console output:
[ { controlType: 'text',
    label: 'name',
    required: false,
    placeholder: 'first name' } ]

But when I print a single field using **req.body.controlType** it prints false on console. I don't know why?
Its the mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

var formSchema = new Schema({    
    controlType: {type: String, required: true},   
    label: {type: String, required: true},
    required: {type: Boolean}, 
    placeholder: {type: String},   
    options: [String],    //to store options for select or radio input
} ,  {collection: 'inputForm'});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema);
```

its my post route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var Form = require('../../models/form');

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('api works');
});

router.post('/userform', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('in form api 0528');
    var keyName1=req.body;
    console.log(keyName1);

    var form = new Form({
        controlType: req.body.controlType,
        label: req.body.label,
        required:req.body.required ,        
        placeholder: req.body.placeholder,
        options: req.body.options
    });
    form.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred in form api 0528',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Form created',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Before saving try to print the req.body.controlType. Is it print what you send in request?

Comment: If I print req.body it prints all the fields with their correct values, see the console output: [ { controlType: 'text', label: 'name', required: false, placeholder: 'first name' } ]

But when I print a single field using req.body.controlType it prints false on console. I don't know why? @PavanVora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your req.body is returning and array. Try something like req.body[0].contentType. I'm not sure but you can give it a try. Tell me if it solved your problem or not.